# Filemaker returns error 500 (Date value does not meet validation entry options)

Tags: php, api, filemaker

I'm using Filemaker ( which I'm not super familiar with ) and it's returning error 500, which means according to the docs:

> Date value does not meet validation entry options

I'm passing the following date format ( as a string ):

```
string(10) "25/09/1988"
```

This is the error that is returned.

```
object(FileMaker_Error)#134 (9) {
["_fm"]=>
&object(FileMaker_Implementation)#3 (3) {
  ["V73ee434e"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["charset"]=>
    string(5) "UTF-8"
    ["locale"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["logLevel"]=>
    int(3)
    ["hostspec"]=>
    string(12) "81.83.29.158"
    ["recordClass"]=>
    string(16) "FileMaker_Record"
    ["prevalidate"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["database"]=>
    string(19) "administratie.fmp12"
    ["username"]=>
    string(11) "blankedout"
    ["password"]=>
    string(11) "blankedout"
  }
  ["Vea4b3413"]=>
  NULL
  ["V9a3dcbce"]=>
  NULL
}
["error_message_prefix"]=>
string(0) ""
["mode"]=>
int(1)
["level"]=>
int(1024)
["code"]=>
string(3) "500"
["message"]=>
NULL
["userinfo"]=>
NULL
["backtrace"]=>
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(62) "/data/sites/web/babydealtoday/www/includes/FileMaker/Error.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(52)
    ["function"]=>
    string(10) "PEAR_Error"
    ["class"]=>
    string(10) "PEAR_Error"
    ["object"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      NULL
      [1]=>
      string(3) "500"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(90) "/data/sites/web/babydealtoday/www/includes/FileMaker/Implementation/Parser/FMResultSet.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(48)
    ["function"]=>
    string(15) "FileMaker_Error"
    ["class"]=>
    string(15) "FileMaker_Error"
    ["object"]=>
    *RECURSION*
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      &object(FileMaker_Implementation)#3 (3) {
        ["V73ee434e"]=>
        array(9) {
          ["charset"]=>
          string(5) "UTF-8"
          ["locale"]=>
          string(2) "en"
          ["logLevel"]=>
          int(3)
          ["hostspec"]=>
          string(12) "81.83.29.158"
          ["recordClass"]=>
          string(16) "FileMaker_Record"
          ["prevalidate"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["database"]=>
          string(19) "administratie.fmp12"
          ["username"]=>
          string(11) "blankedout"
          ["password"]=>
          string(11) "blankedout"
        }
        ["Vea4b3413"]=>
        NULL
        ["V9a3dcbce"]=>
        NULL
      }
      [1]=>
      NULL
      [2]=>
      string(3) "500"
    }
  }
```

This is the field in the Filemaker Software itself

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try entering that same date string in using FM Pro and see if you get an error. It is likely that the OS is not set to use the proper date format, if the default is set to the US standard MM/DD/YYYY. FileMaker uses the date format that is configured at the system level.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the Filemaker Pro Database in the software itself, The date is in the correct format there. Thanks for your answer

Comment: From reading around a bit, could this be a bug in the web publishing engine that does not respect the system format settings and enforces US style dates? Could you test by formatting as US and see if that works?

Comment: It's fixed now. Thanks to your answer and the one above. It was the US format that I have to specify, but it internally transforms it into a European format

Answer (score 1):

2 thougts:

1. In FileMaker's Manage Database dialog, I'd confirm whether the field is defined as a text or data field. While you're here, in the Validation pane, check whether there are any validation constraints set for this field. In addition to the obvious validation settings, also check if there's a validation calculation set. If this is all clear, you can rule out validation errors.
2. It's also possible that the format of your date text may be the issue. I've heard of some cases where FileMaker incorrectly expects US date or number formats in European locales. So I'd try using US date format (mm/dd/yyyy) in a test case. If this doesn't resolve the issue, I'd also suggest experimenting with delimiters, perhaps trying - or . instead of / .

Comment: It was the date, I have to enter a US date, but the engine then transforms it into a european date for reading. Very strange! Thanks for the advice.